# How to run a loop of queries in access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, loops

I have a database with a table which is full of conditions and error messages for checking another database.

I want to run a loop such that each of these conditions is checked against all the tables in the second database and generae a report which gives the errors.

Is this possible in ms access.

For example,

querycrit table

```
id           query                                 error    
1           speed<25 and speed>56              speed above limit  
2           dist<56 or dist >78                dist within limit
```

I have more than 400 queries like this of different variables.

THe table against which I am running the queries is

records table

```
id   speed     dist    accce   decele   aaa   bbb     ccc
1     33        34      44         33   33     33      33
2     45        44      55         55   55     22      23
```

regards
ttk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some more sample code. It illustrates the use of two different types of recordsets. You may wish to read [VBA Traps: Working with Recordsets](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-29.html) by Allen Browne and [List of reserved words in Access 2002 and in later versions of Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335) 
.

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As ADODB.Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("querycrit")
Set rs2 = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs2.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
'EDIT: TableDefs includes Microsoft System tables and '
'these should never be tampered with. They all begin with Msys '
'so we can leave them out of the loop here. '
   If Left(tdf.Name, 4) <> "msys" And tdf.Name <> "querycrit" Then
        rs.MoveFirst
        strSQL = "SELECT * From [" & tdf.Name & "] WHERE "

        Do While Not rs.EOF
            On Error Resume Next
            Debug.Print tdf.Name
            rs2.Open strSQL & " " & rs![query]
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Not rs2.EOF Then
                    Debug.Print rs![Error]
                    Debug.Print rs2.GetString
                End If
            End If
            Err.Clear
            rs2.Close
            rs.MoveNext

        Loop
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: here i am getting a runtime error 3734 at 
For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs

i have defined tdf as tabledef

Comment: i have a doubt in this code. suppose rs2 has a number of records froma table then this will run teh query against only one record rite not all records?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "report", do you mean an Access Report, or would writing to a file or Access Form work?

You can create a function or sub in a Module to do this. Open a recordset on your querycrit table and spin through the records dynamically building and running the SQL for the records table. You can write the results of these dynamic queries to a file, or a form, or insert the results into a temp table and drive the Access Report from there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code, it is typed, not tested.

```
Dim rs AS DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 AS DAO.Recordset

Set rs=CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("querycrit")

strSQL="SELECT * From Records WHERE "
Do While Not rs.EOF
   Set rs2=CurrentDB.OpenRecordset(strSQL & rs![Query])
   If Not rs2.EOF Then
       Debug.Print rs![Error]
       Debug.Print rs2.Fields(1)
   End If

   rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

> "actually there are many record tables
>   to be checked and not all queries can
>   be run on all tables, for eg in one
>   table speed may not be there and in
>   next table distance may not be there."

The correct think to do, I think, would be to create a table of tables and a query-table junction table that shows which queries are to be run on which table, for example:

```
TableID  QueryID
1           4
2           1
2           3
3           1
```

This can the be used to run the correct set of queries on each table.