# Check/update a row of values based on a single column header

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I have  database with many tables. In the first table, I have a field called `status`.

```
table 1
idno   name    status
111    hjghf   yes
225    hjgjj   no
345    hgj     yes
```

Other tables could have same `idno` with different fields.

I want to check the status for each id no and if it is yes then for that id number in all tables for all null and blank fields I want to update them as 111111.

I am looking for a sample vba code for this which I can adapt.

Thanks

Comment: This question is probably related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233026/how-to-run-a-loop-of-queries-in-access

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is some largely untested code. Hopefully it will give you a start.

```
Sub UpdateNulls()
Dim strSQL As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    If Left(tdf.Name, 4) <> "Msys" And tdf.Name <> "Table1" Then
        strSQL = "Select * From [" & tdf.Name & "] a Inner Join " _
        & "Table1 On a.idno = Table1.idno Where Table1.Status = 'Yes'"

        Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

        Do While Not rs.EOF
            For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
                If IsNull(rs.Fields(i)) Then
                    rs.Edit
                    rs.Fields(i) = 111111
                    rs.Update
                End If
            Next
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop

    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Multi-table update syntax for MS Access:

```
UPDATE Table2
INNER JOIN Table1
  ON Table2.idno = Table1.idno
SET Table2.salary = 111111
WHERE Table1.status = 'yes'
AND Table2.salary Is Null
```

You can go into SQL View for a query, paste this in, and then run the query, or assign it to a string and use CurrentDb.Execute or CurrentProject.Connection.Execute, depending on your DAO/ADO preference.